# Trouble pushing barebones app to Heroku with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

We have an app that's been running on Heroku (bamboo) for over a year. When pushing a change yesterday, the push was rejected when it failed to install the paperclip gem. No changes had been made to the gem list up to the point of failure. I tried a brand new, barebones app and got the same result. It seems the bamboo stack has changed in some way. Anybody else experiencing this or know what might be going on?

Here are repro steps:

```
$ rails temp-app
$ cd temp-app
$ cat >.gems
rails -v 2.3.14
paperclip -v 2.5.0
<control-D>
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "init"
$ heroku create --stack bamboo
$ git push heroku master
```

this is the output:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done

-----> Installing gem rails 2.3.14 from http://rubygems.org
       Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.14
       Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.14
       Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.14
       Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.14
       Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.14
       Successfully installed rails-2.3.14
       6 gems installed

-----> Installing gem paperclip 2.5.0 from http://rubygems.org
       ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
           undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gem
```

Comment: Also recommend heroku support for this --- someone here might have experienced this lately, but I'd start a ticket there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did get an answer from Heroku support: Paperclip specifies a dependency on Active Record like this: 'activerecord', '>= 2.3.0' which causes the latest AR version to be installed. The latest version as of a few days ago is 3.2, which is broken on Rails 2.3, hence the failure.

I solved this by adding --ignore-dependencies to the paperclip gem in .gems and manually adding dependencies to .gems.